# How to get Server Stats like CPU Usage, Response time etc. when Load has been applied from Client PC

Tags: automated-testing, tools, browser-automation, load-testing, jmeter

How to get Server Stats like CPU Usage, Response time etc. when Load has been applied from Client PC.

I am Using Blazemeter with Jmeter on Ubuntu 12.04 OS.

Thanks Expert for being on Stack Exchange.

Answer (score 1):

I vouch for [dstat](http://dag.wiee.rs/home-made/dstat/).
Simply start it before running the test, it can save results in csv file so you can later xanalyze it with jmeter results. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If your application server is Tomcat or JBoss you can query this information via [Monitor Results](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Monitor_Results) listener

In other case it is still possible via [PerfMon JMeter Plugin](http://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/PerfMon/) which can collect different server side metrics like CPU, Memory, swap, disk and network IO on almost all platforms.

Blazemeter supports all the plugins assuming that you upload associated .jar files along with your test script .jmx file

Answer (score 0):

If your server application turns on JAVA you can use jconsole or jvisualvm to monitor it.
They are located in your $JAVA_HOME/bin from your server. 
Before to launch them you need to export your X11 display: 
export DISPLAY=11.11.111.111:0.0 (Replace 111 by the IP of your client machine)
On your server side launch jconsole or jvisualvm, it will be opened on your client machine.